# How to assign nsstring to nsurl?

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsurl

I am working with the url my code is like below

```
NSString *finalURLString1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" https://myservices/uploads/main/fullimage/%@.jpg",myNewString];
NSString *finalURLString =[finalURLString1 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL];
```

But I am getting like below

```
%20https://myservice/uploads/main/fullimage/917696.jpg
```

Where I'm missing.

Comment: You are missing the simple fact that you have a space character where it doesn't belong.

Comment: There is a space character before `http://`: `...@" https://`

Comment: I'm so stupid  Thank you very much.

Comment: BTW - don't escape the entire final URL. Just escape values you are applying as query parameters or as arguments to `stringWithFormat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *finalURLString1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://myservices/uploads/main/fullimage/%@.jpg",myNewString];
NSString *finalURLString =[finalURLString1 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL];
```

Removed space from url, now you'll get done.